# How to setup setseed for one's Rcpp function using RcppZiggurat samplers?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am developing some sampling algorithms based on **RcppZiggurat**. My objective is to use the samplers in **cpp** code but not having to come up with new ways of setting the seed but to rely on existing functions, such as `RcppZiggurat::zsetseed`.

This are my two **cpp** functions using the sampler `zigg.norm()`:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <Ziggurat.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppZiggurat)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

static Ziggurat::Ziggurat::Ziggurat zigg;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec zzrnorm(int n) {
  vec x(n);
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    x(i) = zigg.norm();
  }
  return x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec zzrnorm_ss(int n, unsigned long int set_seed) {
  zigg.setSeed(set_seed);
  vec x(n);
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    x(i) = zigg.norm();
  }
  return x;
}
```

And here is the R code and outputs that I am studying and cannot understand the outputs:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("so_Ziggurat.cpp")
> RcppZiggurat::zsetseed(1)
> RcppZiggurat::zrnorm(3)
[1] -1.4808858  0.9991196 -0.4898021

> RcppZiggurat::zsetseed(1)
> RcppZiggurat::zrnorm(3)
[1] -1.4808858  0.9991196 -0.4898021

> RcppZiggurat::zsetseed(1)

> zzrnorm(3)
           [,1]
[1,] -1.1409054
[2,]  0.8759027
[3,] -0.1969075

> RcppZiggurat::zsetseed(1)

> zzrnorm(3)
           [,1]
[1,] -0.1245053
[2,]  0.2695581
[3,] -0.4185105

> zzrnorm_ss(3, 1)
           [,1]
[1,] -1.4808858
[2,]  0.9991196
[3,] -0.4898021

> zzrnorm_ss(3, 1)
           [,1]
[1,] -1.4808858
[2,]  0.9991196
[3,] -0.4898021
```

The first two generators are from the **RcppZiggyrat** and use `RcppZiggurat::zsetseed` to set seed and `RcppZiggurat::zrnorm` to generate random numbers. They are reproducible, of course.

The second set of outputs is something I don't understand. I use the package provided `RcppZiggurat::zsetseed` to set seed and my function `zzrnorm` to sample random numbers. My function uses the same class of samplers for which `RcppZiggurat::zsetseed` sets the seed based on

```
static Ziggurat::Ziggurat::Ziggurat zigg;
```

But `RcppZiggurat::zsetseed` does not set the seed, and the generated numbers differ despite the fact that `RcppZiggurat::zsetseed` uses the same source code: `zigg.setSeed(set_seed);` to set the seed.

Now, if I include `RcppZiggurat::zsetseed` within my function as in the third example then the seed is set properly and the results are reproducible.

So, why isn't that the case in the second set of outputs?

I would greatly appreciate some suggestions as this would be my preferred way of working with the samplers in R.

Answer (score 3):

Nice puzzle.  I think the key is that your two calls in the middle call *your call local instance* which has been initialized with the *default* seed. Witness an Rscript call on the command-line with defaults getting the same six values:

```
$ Rscript -e 'RcppZiggurat::zrnorm(6)'       
[1] -1.140905  0.875903 -0.196907 -0.124505  0.269558 -0.418510  
$
```

So to make the calls comparable, you need to set seeds. A simpler version follow.  Here we call the instance from the package twice, with seeding, and then your instance, also with seeding.  Unsurprisingly, the results are the same.

##### Code

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <Ziggurat.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppZiggurat)]]

static Ziggurat::Ziggurat::Ziggurat zigg;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::rowvec zzrnorm_ss(int n, unsigned long int set_seed) {
  zigg.setSeed(set_seed);
  arma::rowvec x(n);
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    x(i) = zigg.norm();
  }
  return x;
}

/*** R
RcppZiggurat::zsetseed(1)
v1 <- RcppZiggurat::zrnorm(3)
RcppZiggurat::zsetseed(1)
v2 <- RcppZiggurat::zrnorm(3)
v3 <- zzrnorm_ss(3, 1)
v4 <- zzrnorm_ss(3, 1)
rbind(v1, v2, v3, v4)
*/
```

##### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/73679283/answer.cpp")

> RcppZiggurat::zsetseed(1)

> v1 <- RcppZiggurat::zrnorm(3)

> RcppZiggurat::zsetseed(1)

> v2 <- RcppZiggurat::zrnorm(3)

> v3 <- zzrnorm_ss(3, 1)

> v4 <- zzrnorm_ss(3, 1)

> rbind(v1, v2, v3, v4)
       [,1]    [,2]      [,3]
v1 -1.48089 0.99912 -0.489802
v2 -1.48089 0.99912 -0.489802
   -1.48089 0.99912 -0.489802
   -1.48089 0.99912 -0.489802
>
```

Comment: Hi Dirk! Thanks for your answer! Needless, to add that I really admire how promptly you reply to all the Rcpp-related questions! AMAZING! So, basically, you recommend not to use the way of (NOT) setting seed as in my middle example. That's alright, of course. I was just hoping for some standard way of setting seed for my package by simply using RcppZiggurat::zsetseed and not in a function argument. But that's fine and can be explained in the documentation! :)

Comment: Not exactly what I was saying. Your middle two calls go to a _different_ Ziggurat instance which you _had not initialized_. That is all.  There is no requirement to alway pass the seed (but your example is more complicated than usual as you have two Ziggurat objects, which is not the recommend usage way).